# WCF with HTTPS and Windows Phone 8

Tags: wcf, azure, https, certificate, windows-phone-8

I am working on a small service accessed from a client on Windows Phone 8 and/or WinRT device that requires a moderate amount of security. My goal is to create a service that runs in Windows Azure.

My application requires authentication that verifies two things:
1) Authenticity of the client
2) User credentials of the client

Step 1) I need be certain to a fair degree that the application calling the service is, in fact, my client application.

Step 2) The user needs to have an account in the system that can be authenticated. I can implement the authentication by simply making a Login() method in the interface (unless there is a better way). However, for this, the communication between the client and the server needs to be secure as I do not want my username+password combo unencrypted.

My current view is that implementing it as a WCF service would probably be the way to go as I might have further interest into porting to other platforms on the client-side and a quick look showed me that this is somewhat supported.

However, as I am new to all these certificate shenanigans, my question is whether I can use self-signed certificates for securing my connection? Only my server and my client need to be able to verify the authenticity. Furthermore, any pointers to exactly how this is done in the WP8 + Windows Azure case?

Another deal is that assuming that a nifty hacker breaks open my program from the client hardware, can he take the certificate and use it to create his own client to login with (his) username/password and performing actions performed by my original client? Or is there a way to prevent this on the client side? In other words, can my server be sure of the authenticity of the client software based on having a valid certificate signed by me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 is pretty much impossible. No matter what attestation method you use in code it can be duplicated in code by another programme.

Step 2 doesn't require WCF, although you can use it with basic auth. It's just as easy to expose a RESTful service with WebAPI which supports basic auth as well. Securing the communication is the same for either WCF or WebAPI - use SSL.

WCF does not like self signed certificates, and configuring it to use them does away with some of the security, depending on how you do it. Given that SSL certs from trusted CAs start at around $10 it would be a false economy not to get one. Azure webworkers support SSL certs, and support for Azure Web Sites is coming, although with no firm date.

Finally a client certificate in managed code can be reasonably easily extracted, so you cannot rely on it to identify client code.